# Zend Framework: PHP script in img src tag causing broken image

Tags: php, image, zend-framework, jpgraph

I'm using the JpGraph library within a [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) project of version 1.11. I'm trying to display the graph of some data using an `img` tag by including a php script in the `src` field, as so:

```
echo "<img src='vgraph.php?param1=val1&param2=val2...
```

When I do this, the only thing displayed as an image is the my browser's default broken image. Since typical URLs in Zend are treated as controller-action pairs, the path to the file I am including is also treated as a controller-action pair. To investigate why I wasn't getting my image, I viewed the source of the page in the browser. When I clicked on the link for the above `img` tag, I was directed to a page containing the error:

```
Invalid controller specified (vgraph.php)
```

I don't by any means intend to use the script as a controller. It is only supposed to display the image of a graph. I am unsure about how to make sure that Zend only uses the file's output as an image, and not to use its path as a URL.

Here is the file I am using for the image, `vgraph.php`:

```
<?php

/* graph the vital data */

require_once( 'path/to/Zend/project/web/library/jpgraph/jpgraph.php' ); 
require_once( 'path/to/Zend/project/web/library/jpgraph/jpgraph_line.php' );

/* get the needed parameters */
$id = $_GET['param1'];
$type = $_GET['param2'];
$from = $_GET['param3'];
$to = $_GET['param4'];

$graph = new Graph( $width, $height );

/* create the data and plot */
$obj = new CcFunc_VitalSigns();
$vitals = $obj->getVitalData( $id, $type, $from, $to );

/* configure everything */
$graph->setScale( 'intint' );
$graph->title->Set( "Graph of " . $type );
$graph->xaxis->title->Set( "X-Axis" );
$graph->yaxis->title->Set( "Numerical Value" );

$lp = new LinePlot( $vitals );
$lp->setColor( 'blue' );    
$lp->setWeight( 5 );

/* add the plot to the graph */
$graph->Add( $lp );

/* display the graph */
$graph->Stroke();
```

**NOTE:** I've tried other solutions, such as streaming the graph to a `png` file and letting the `src` field be the URL of *that* file, but I was met with the same problem, even after adding a `RewriteRule` to apache to prevent redirection of `.png` files. I've settled upon this method as the most comfortable (potential) solution.

**EDIT:** I didn't say this before, but the code where the `img` tag is echo'd is *not* a controller, and is actually located in `path/to/Zend/roject/web/application/scripts/views`. The script `vgraph.php` is located in `path/to/Zend/project/web/library`.

Comment: Where is the vgraph.php file located, and what does your htaccess file look like?

Comment: I added the file locations in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the vgraph.php file to your public folder for this to work, the browser isn't able to view files outside of that.

Move it to `path/to/Zend/project/web/public/vgraph.php`, change your img tag to `<img src="/vgraph.php?param1=val1&param2=val2...` and everything should work as you expect.

Comment: It didnt work for me...I have copied an image from local disk to public folder(public/uploads/) through code and tried to retrieve the image using img src tag but image is not shown.@Tim Fountain

Answer (score -1):

When linking try in the view to specify the full path as:

```
<?php echo $this->baseURL();?>
```

[Zend View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

This will return localhos/[APP]/

Hope this helps

Try to put everything in a Graph controller within a generateAction method and you can link to it:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->baseURL();?>/graph/generate/?param1=val1&param2=val2...">Generate</a>
```

Comment: So would it be best to just put all of the graphing code into a controller? Is there really no way to get past Zend's URL structure?

Comment: I guess you can change the .htaccess to redirect requests that don`t have '.php' extension I guess, don`t know regex well enough

Comment: But the file I'm using is a php file, and thus has a '.php' extension. I'm asking if there's any way to prevent Zend from redirecting this specific path.

Comment: I downvoted because your answer focused on using the baseURL helper to alter the path being output, but since the graph can't be viewed directly by URL, the path isn't the issue.

Comment: I also said he should move this in a controller and to use the view helper because one can have issues with linking. The real problem is that if you are using a framework why should you write code outside a controller...